# Remove suffix from a directory's name

Tags: batch-file, directory, findstr

A short foreword: currently working with a very awkward setup; the company we have been contracted with requires us to perform all operations in batch, because of potential dangers of downloaded software and all that bureaucracy. So I have to work purely in batch for this problem - no addins, downloads, or PowerShell suggestions please (:p).

**QUESTION:**

Imagine a directory containing directories, e.g.,

- Parent Folder

  - Subfolder
  - Subfolder(1)
  - Subfolder(2)

They've all been uniquely reference as such:

- Parent Folder

  - REF231_Subfolder
  - REF527_Subfolder(1)
  - REF8837_Subfolder(2)

Now we want to remove those suffixes added to prevent duplicate names! So, with batch's rather challenging syntax for string replacement, it has proved quite an issue. Let me walk you through the code I currently have, which doesn't work, but may be of use:

```
@ECHO off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: This returns all directories (/a:d), then pipes that to a findstr command,
:: that identifies the prefix at the end of the directory name.
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a:d ^| findstr ^.*^(*^)$') do (
   set F=%%F 
   set suffix=^(!F:*^(=!
   echo !suffix!
   set newname=!F:!suffix!=!
   echo !newname!
)

pause
```

**PROBLEM:**

I would expect `set newname=!F:!suffix!=!` to replace the value of `!suffix!` within the string F, which is the directory name, and then set this to the variable `!newname!`. Why instead does `!newname!` equal the same as `!suffix!`?

Also, please note I've tried using `%suffix%`, and a myriad of other variable syntaxes, all to no avail.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!var1:!var2!=!` (that is delayed expansion inside delayed expansion) is not allowed (can not be correctly parsed). And in your case `!var1:%var2%=!` with var2 value changing inside the `for` block will not work (there is no delayed expansion for `var2`).

To make your code work you need something like

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a:d ^| findstr /r /c:"^.*\(.*\)$"') do (
    echo %%F
    set "F=%%F"
    set "suffix=(!F:*(=!"
    echo !suffix!
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ("!suffix!") do set "newname=!F:%%~a=!"
    echo !newname!
)
```

that is, as you can not write a delayed expansion inside a delayed expansion, replace the inner variable with a `for` replaceable parameter.

Anyway, this case can be simplified.

```
for /d %%a in ( "*(*)" 
) do for /f "delims=(" %%b in ("%%~na"
) do echo ren "%%~fa" "%%~b"
```

For each folder with a parenthesis, take its name, and split it at the parenthesis. First token will hold the new name without the suffix. Then the `ren` command will rename the folder (full path to it) with the new name.

`ren` commands are echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` to rename the folders.

Comment: +1, but this assumes there are no additional parentheses in name, as does the OP's original algorithm. That is probably a safe bet, but there is a [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24451802/1012053)

Comment: Accepted as this is a wonderful refactor on the original code, and solves my problem - although @dbenham more correctly answered it, you win for timeliness. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your original algorithm, and [both MC ND's solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24448907/1012053) assume there are no additional parentheses in the folder name. Also, MC ND's first solution also assumes there are no `!` in the folder name. Both assumptions are probably safe, but there is a fairly simple solution that properly handles those unlikely complications:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b /ad "*(*)"^|findstr /r "^[^.][^.]*([0-9][0-9]*)$'
) do (
  pushd \
  set "old=%%F"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set "new=!old:(=x\!"
  for %%A in ("!new!") do endlocal & set "new=%%~pA"
  popd
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set "new=!new:~1,-2!"
  set "new=!new:x\=(!"
  echo ren "!old!" "!new!"
  endlocal
)
```

If everything looks correct, simply remove the ECHO to activate the REN command.

Comment: For this dataset, I know that there are no additional parentheses, although I didn't consider that - I used the `$` character in the piped directory name to make sure the last parenthesis is at least at the end of the string. Great consideration for the question at hand though, +1

Comment: +1 `pushd \ ` + `%%~pA` Really clever! Anyway both your code and mine (the nested for) fail for `(this)` folder.

Comment: @MCND - Addition of FINDSTR can easily handle `(this)` and others. I modified my answer a bit.

Comment: I've been testing the way you remove the last element. Maybe i'm not seeing something obvious, but it seems the `pushd / popd` can be removed changing to `set "new=!old:(=\!"`, `for %%A in ("\:!new!") do ...` ... `set "new=!new:~2,-1!"` , `set "new=!new:\=(!"`

Comment: I don't see how that can work because `set "new=%%~pA"` will prefix the value with the path to the current directory.